# Printing ArrayList contents into a TextArea

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists called *keys* and *values*.

```
keys = {"cat", "dog", "mouse"}
values = {"furry;white", "greyhound;beast", "little;rat"}
```

I would like to have them printed in a JTextArea (since I want them to be editable) or any other GUI component  like this:

```
------------------
cat   |   furry
      |   white
-------------------
dog   |   greyhound
      |   beast
-------------------
mouse |   little
      |   rat
```

Should I create a new TextArea dynamically for each entry? If so how do I do that? Is that the right approach?

I have already tried using JTable but the issue with that is the cell height is fixed and text wrapping is a mess.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: If you want each separate value to be editable you would be better off generating separate editable fields within a panel. You can lay them out using `GridLayout`.

Comment: Why not using `Map` for key and value pair ?

Comment: @NeerajJain: Could you please explain more on that?

Comment: Using JTable is fine, you just need to create a custom Cell renderer for the second column

Comment: @summerNight Check out the Answer , i have explained there .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **GridLayout**

```
Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>(); //key-Value pair
map.put("cat",""furry\n white"); // \n So that you will get a new line character in text area
map.put("dog","greyhound \n beast");
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows,columns));//In your case (map.size,2)
frame.setSize(300, 300);

//Now You need to Iterate through the Map.

for(Map.Entry<String,String>entry:map.entrySet()){
  JTextArea left=JTextArea(entry.getKey());
  JTextArea right=JTextArea(entry.getValue());
  frame.add(left);  //Adding each key to the Frame on left side
  frame.add(right); //This is the value you want in side of key
 }

frame.setVisible(true);
```

You will get something like this but in editable format

[image]

> I have two ArrayLists called keys and values.
>
> ```
> keys = {"cat", "dog", "mouse"} 
> values = {"furry;white", "greyhound;beast", "little;rat"}
> ```

As you can see you are maintaining the List of keys and value seperately which is a bad practice , you can have [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) (just read this link, it wil be helpfull) which stores the `key` and it's corresponding `value` in a single record ,

**Now A little  Suggestion**

If you want to use `multiple values` against one `key` I suggest you to use [MultiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) which maintains multiple values against one single key , It's very usefull library .

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest having separate `JTextField` instances for each editable field and then lay them out using a `GridLayout`. Your code would end up something like this method to create a panel with the fields in it.

```
public JPanel createPanelForStringMap(Map<String, String> map) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(map.size(), 2));
    for (Map.Entry entry: map.entrySet()) {
        panel.add(new JTextField(entry.getKey()));
        panel.add(new JTextField(entry.getValue()));
    }
    return panel;
}
```

Naturally you'd need to add code to do something with the values once they've been edited.